# Shape drawable not stretched as ImageView's background

Tags: android

**Shape Drawable: avatar_mask.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:thicknessRatio="2">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/mask_color" />    

</shape>
```

**Layout**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar_mask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/avatar_mask"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In ADT's Graphic Layout, it looks OK:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHHYJ.png)

while on real device, it looks like this, this avatar_mask ring is displayed as a line, not stretched to parent size:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w73j6.png)

Comment: try to set src attribute to imageview android:src="@drawable/avatar_mask"

Comment: Like that picture :)

Comment: where is your @dimen/avatar_size file?

Comment: @JittyAandyan I've tried this approach, still the same

Comment: @RahulPatidar res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: That i know but post that file too